# Aspose Cells for Java: get original CSV row

Tags: java, csv, aspose-cells

I am using Aspose to read a CSV file.

I do not beforehand know the number of cells for each row of the file, but I will need to know it for further processing.

Unfortunately, I see no way to find out the number of cells in a CSV row.

Imagine the following row in the CSV file. It contains 7 cells, 4 of which are empty:

```
1,2,,4,,,
```

Using

```
row.iterator();
```

Aspose will only return 3 cells, as it ignores all empty cells.

As an alternative, I now do the following:

```
    Cell lastCell = row.getLastCell();

    int count = 0;
    do {
        cell = row.getCellOrNull(count);
        String cellValue = cell == null ? "" : cell.getStringValueWithoutFormat();

        //do something with the cell value...

        count++;
    } while (cell == null || ! lastCell.equals(cell));
```

This works better, as it returns the first 4 cells.
However, it still ignores the last 3 cells .

Is there any way to get information about the missing cells?
(It would be sufficient for me if Aspose could return the original Row as a String - I could then count the number of commas and find out the number of cells this way)

Answer (score 0):

You may use **Worksheet.getCells().getMaxDisplayRange()** method to get the maximum display range.

Please consider this CSV. If you open it in MS-Excel and check the last cell, you will find it is Q2

**Book1.csv**

```
2,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,3,,,,
```

Aspose.Cells returns the same via the following code.

```
TxtLoadOptions opts = new TxtLoadOptions(LoadFormat.CSV);

Workbook wb = new Workbook("Book1.csv", opts);
Worksheet ws = wb.getWorksheets().get(0);
Range rng = ws.getCells().getMaxDisplayRange();

System.out.println(rng);
```

Here is the console output of the code.

**Console Output**

```
Aspose.Cells.Range [ Sheet1!A1:Q2 ]
```

*Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose*

Comment: Unfortunately, I have different rows with different number of cells each. With your solution, I only get the number of cells for the longest row.

Comment: I have looked into this issue and I thought, instead of using Aspose.Cells, you can directly read csv lines using Java APIs and then count commas inside it. I tried some Java codes but unfortunately, those codes do not read empty csv lines, but they do read those lines which have at least one cell non-empty. You can also post your issue in Aspose.Cells forums, then we will add a new feature in Aspose.Cells to fulfill your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, I posted this here: http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/showthread.aspx?PostID=719442&Subj=aspose-cells-for-java-get-original-csv-row#719442

Comment: @stefan.m,
Please check your thread in Aspose.Cells support forum for possible solutions for presented scenario. http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/719442/719558/showthread.aspx#719558

Comment: Note: Aspose informed me that this will not be implemented. See http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/showthread.aspx?PostID=719442&Subj=aspose-cells-for-java-get-original-csv-row#719442